# Blank Screen OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn how to do some basic rendering in OpenGL 2.0, with shader programs, and I'm having difficulties getting any vertex data to show up on the screen. Right now I'm at a loss for where my problem is. I've gone through a number of examples and nothing obvious stands out for me as wrong in my code, but I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I'll try to be short with my code.

I've also asked the same question here: [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47414/blank-screen-open-gl-2-0), but unfortunately I have not received any answers that were able to solve my problem.

Quick summary of the attempted answers:

1. I can clear the background color to red, so I know my display code works.
2. The camera code does not modify the matrix stack.
3. There are no shader compiler errors.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
bool GameCore::Start(int iCmdShow)
{
    const LPCWSTR appname = TEXT("Maze Game");
    // Create the Window and kill the program if this fails.
    if(!wm->Create(appname))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Initialize OpenGL
    wm->InitGraphics();
    cam = wm->cam;

    Vector3 *v = new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    wm->testSprite = new Sprite(v);

    // Start the update loop.
    _beginthread(&GameCore::Execute, 0, this);

    // Blocking function to run the application.
    wm->RunWindow(iCmdShow);
    return true;
}

// Initialize OpenGL graphics
void OpenGLWM::InitGraphics()
{
    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    SetupPixelFormat();

    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        // Add error handling.
    }

    cam = new Camera(0, 0, -10);
    program = new ShaderProgram();
    program->Initialize();
}

// Set up pixel format for graphics initialization
void OpenGLWM::SetupPixelFormat()
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd, *ppfd;
    int pixelformat;

    ppfd = &pfd;

    ppfd->nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    ppfd->nVersion = 1;
    ppfd->dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    ppfd->dwLayerMask = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    ppfd->iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX;
    ppfd->cColorBits = 16;
    ppfd->cDepthBits = 16;
    ppfd->cAccumBits = 0;
    ppfd->cStencilBits = 0;

    pixelformat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, ppfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelformat, ppfd);
}

// Camera Constructor
Camera::Camera(double dX, double dY, double dZ)
{
    Vector3 V(dX, dY, dZ);
    Vector3 R(0,0,0);
    Initialization(V, R);
}

bool ShaderProgram::Initialize()
{
    GLint giLinked;
    GLbyte vShaderStr[] =
    "#version 110               \n"
    "attribute vec3 in_Position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    GLbyte pShaderStr[] =
    "#version 110               \n"
    "precision mediump float;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    // Load the shaders
    vertexShader.LoadShader((const char *)&vShaderStr, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    pixelShader.LoadShader((const char *)&pShaderStr, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    guiProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if(guiProgram == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Add the shaders to the program
    glAttachShader(guiProgram, vertexShader.guiShader);
    glAttachShader(guiProgram, pixelShader.guiShader);

    // Bind the position coordinates
    glBindAttribLocation(guiProgram, 0, "in_Position");

    // Link the program
    glLinkProgram(guiProgram);
    int iError = glGetError();
    // Get the link status
    glGetProgramiv(guiProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &giLinked);

    if(giLinked == 0)
    {
        // Add error handling.
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

GLuint BaseShader::LoadShader(const char *cShaderSrc, GLenum type)
{
    GLint guiCompiled;
    // Creates an empty shader object.
    guiShader = glCreateShader(type);

    if(guiShader == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Load the shader.
    glShaderSource(guiShader, 1, &cShaderSrc, NULL);

    // Compile the shader
    glCompileShader(guiShader);

    // Check the compile status
    glGetShaderiv(guiShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &guiCompiled);

    if(guiCompiled == 0)
    {
        // TODO: ADD ERROR LOGGING
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(guiShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
        if(infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(guiShader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            free(infoLog);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return guiShader;
}

// Sprite inherits from Render Object
Sprite::Sprite(Vector3 *_vPosition)
{
    // Initialize the position.
    vPosition = _vPosition;
    // Create verticies
    vertexStruct * v = new vertexStruct[4];
    v[0].SetPosition(-2, 2, -40);
    v[0].SetColor(128, 128, 128, 255);
    v[1].SetPosition(2, 2, -40);
    v[1].SetColor(128, 128, 128, 255);
    v[2].SetPosition(2, -2, -40);
    v[2].SetColor(128, 128, 128, 255);
    v[3].SetPosition(-2, -2, -40);
    v[3].SetColor(128, 128, 128, 255);

    // Create the indicies.
    GLubyte * i = new GLubyte[6];
    i[0] = 0;
    i[1] = 1;
    i[2] = 2;
    i[3] = 0;
    i[4] = 2;
    i[5] = 3;

    Initialize(v, 4, i, 6);
}

void RenderObject::Initialize(vertexStruct *_vertices, unsigned int _uiNumVertices, GLubyte *_indices, unsigned int _uiNumIndicies)
{
    vertices = _vertices;
    indices = _indices;
    uiNumVertices = _uiNumVertices;
    uiNumIndices = _uiNumIndicies;
    CreateBufferObjects();
}

void RenderObject::CreateBufferObjects()
{
    // Get an id for the Vector3 buffer.
    glGenBuffers((GLsizei)1, &uiVertexBuffer);
    // Bind the buffer so we can "upload" the data.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexBuffer);
    // Upload the data to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexStruct) * uiNumVertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Get an id for the indice buffer.
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiIndiceBuffer);
    // Bind the indice buffer so we can "upload" the data.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiIndiceBuffer);
    // Upload the data to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte) * uiNumIndices, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

bool WindowManager::RunWindow(int iCmdShow)
{
    // Display the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Event loop
    while (1)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) == TRUE)
        {
            if (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        // It would be better if this was its own thread.
        if(!DoWork())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true;
}

// "Draw" function.
bool OpenGLWM::DoWork()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program->guiProgram);

    testSprite->Draw();
    // Show the new scene
    SwapBuffers(hDC);
    return true;
}

void RenderObject::Draw()
{
    // Bind the vertex buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexBuffer);
    // Set where the vertex data is.
    glVertexAttribPointer(VertexEnum::Data, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexStruct), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);//VertexEnum::Data);

    // Load the colors.
    glVertexAttribPointer(VertexEnum::Color, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 12, (void*)offsetof(vertexStruct, color));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);//VertexEnum::Color);
    // Bind the indice buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiIndiceBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, uiNumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

void OpenGLWM::ResizeGraphics()
{
    // Get new window size
    RECT rect;
    int width;
    int height;
    GLfloat aspect;

    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    width = rect.right;
    height = rect.bottom;
    aspect = (GLfloat)width / height;

    // Adjust graphics to window size
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // Call the base function
    WindowManager::ResizeGraphics();
}
```

Comment: @JesseGood If the GPU didn't support shaders, would the shaders compile?

Comment: @JesseGood I'm using a high end graphics card, so it should.

Comment: @leemes: I think it is possible, yes, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: A couple of things to look at:
1) clear the depth buffer (you're missing the GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT in the `glClear` call
2) are you sure `ResizeGraphics()` is called?  If not, I'm not sure you're matrices are configured correctly.

Comment: @radical7 Thanks for the help. 1. Added glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); to no effect. 2. Yes. It the function gets called when the program starts.

Comment: I think your vertex shader isn't taking the matrix transforms into account.  Right now, it's just assigning the vertex position to `gl_Position`.  A quick test would be replace the body of your vertex shader with `gl_Position = ftransform();`  Try that.

Comment: @leemes Shader low-level language is defined as a standard, so you don't have to own shader-supporting GPU to compile them. DirectX SDK has even a small program fxc.exe (Effect Compiler), which compiles .fx shader file to shader object file.

Comment: @radical7 That defiantly is the correct approach! I am still seeing some odd effects though: http://i.imgur.com/KkAR4C9.png. I'm thinking that perhaps something is wrong with how I am setting up the sprite or with how I am using my gluPerspective.

Comment: Looks like depth buffer issues. You are now clearing the depth buffer, but what did you set the depth test to? Less than? Greater than? Also, you only have a 16-bit depth buffer. Is that enough for the vertex data you're using?

Comment: @Alikar You're halfway between solutions.  Your vertex indices are set up for two separate triangles, but you're drawing with a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.  Changing to GL_TRIANGLES in your `glDrawElements` call will fix the problem.  Or changing your index array to only be four vertices (triangle strips use n+2 vertices for n triangles): 1, 0, 3, 2.

Comment: @user1118321 You're correct that it's a depth buffer issue, but not for the reasons you mention.  Alikar's intent (based on his vertex data) is to draw a planar quad, so it should be correct even without a depth buffer.

Comment: @user1118321 Actually looking at my code it looks like I didn't have the depth buffer being clear because it didn't have any affect. I put that back in based on your suggestion and everything worked! Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @radical7 As you can see in my post above the depth buffer bit combined with fTranform did the trick! Can you make an answer to that effect and I'll mark it correct. Thank you! Also I am still able to use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or GL_TRIANGLES without an issue. I'll need to research why both would work, but I figured I'd let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with the program, which combined cause the lack of rendering:

1. First, the transformation of world coordinate vertices to screen coordinates isn't happening.  Specifically, the vertex shader only copies the input vertex values to the final vertex position (what's commonly called a 'pass-thru' shader).  There are multiple solutions to this problem:

   - used the very old `ftransform()` GLSL routine which will return the transformed vertex value:

     ```
     gl_Position = ftransform();
     ```
   - use the implicitly defined GLSL matrices:

     ```
     gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
     ```
   - or use the individually defined matrices:

     ```
     gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
     ```
2. The next issue is that the defined geometry is inconsistent with how it's being rendered.  In particular, the index element array, defined below

   ```
   // Create the indicies.
   GLubyte * i = new GLubyte[6];
   i[0] = 0;
   i[1] = 1;
   i[2] = 2;
   i[3] = 0;
   i[4] = 2;
   i[5] = 3;
   ```

   is for two triangles, however the `glDrawElements` call specifies GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP as the geometric primitive.  This can be fixed in two ways:

   - use GL_TRIANGLES for the geometric primitive type, or
   - repair the index element list for triangle strips to be:

     ```
     // Create the indicies.
     GLubyte * i = new GLubyte[4];
     i[0] = 1;
     i[1] = 0;
     i[2] = 2;
     i[3] = 3;
     ```

   this will yield two triangles in a strip with the appropriate vertex winding for correct back-face culling.
3. Finally, while a depth buffer is requested, and the depth test enabled, the depth buffer isn't cleared each frame.  Adding a GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT to the `glClear` call will accomplish that.